# Two TextBox bound with different value

Tags: c#, loops

I want to convert integer from `TextBox` to another `TextBox`. I have this code, but it only converts at the beginning, and nothing shappen when I change the `TextBox`.

```
int j = 100;
int value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++)
{
    if (AtextBox.Text == i.ToString())
    {
        value = j - i;
        BtextBox.Text = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

How can `BtextBox` changes everytime i change the `AtextBox`?

Comment: On the textChanged event (or similar) set the BtextBox.Text = AtextBox.text.

Comment: BTW, I'm very positive that the above code is running upto 100 times slower than it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use events. Create a `TextChanged` event handler.

There are two ways to do this:

1. Open designer, open Properties of `Atextbox`, find `TextChanged` event and click it twice.
2. Since `TextChanged` is default event for `TextBox`, simply click your `TextBox` twice in designer

Visual Studio will create the following handler:

```
public void Atextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) ...
```

Just add your code to it:

```
public void Atextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int value;
   if (int.TryParse(Atextbox.Text, out value))
   {
       Btextbox.Text = (100 - value).ToString();
   }
}
```

Every time you change the contents of `Atextbox`, it will trigger this event, which will parse integer from your textbox, substract it from 100, and apply it to another textbox.
And, yes, you don't need a loop there.

Comment: umm the line `Btextbox.Text = (100 - value).ToString();` got error occured : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. why?

Comment: @Mirza The only thing that could could happen is that `Btextbox` is null. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: but its not null, i have default value of Btextbox, i also try to fill `Btextbox.Text = "100"` before if statement, but still got same error